# Linq Ordering/Grouping by a min value

Tags: linq

I have a List.

Foo has two properties, CaseId, and PersonId.

I need to sort the list so that they grouped by PersonId, but with the person who has the lowest CaseId first.

So, given this data

```
P1 C19
P2 C23
P2 C24
P1 C28
P3 C07
P2 C32
P3 C60
P1 C20
```

It gets sorted as

```
P3 C07
P3 C60
P1 C19
P1 C20
P1 C28
P2 C23
P2 C24
P2 C32
```

I can't figure out how to write this as a LINQ query.

Comment: @FrankPl, nothing that compiles...my brain has already started the weekend. Obviously simple OrderBy's fail.  Grouping results in objects that are groups, not `Foo`s, and posting a dozen samples of code that clearly don't complile is a waste of all our time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one:

```
var persons = new[] {
    new Foo { PersonId = "P1", CaseId = "C19" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P2", CaseId = "C23" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P2", CaseId = "C24" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P1", CaseId = "C28" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P3", CaseId = "C07" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P2", CaseId = "C32" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P3", CaseId = "C60" },
    new Foo { PersonId = "P1", CaseId = "C20" },
};

var res = (from p in persons
           group p by p.PersonId into q
           orderby q.Min(r => r.CaseId)
           select q).ToArray();
```

will do as requested.

You `group by` `PersonId` and then `orderby` the `Min(r => r.CaseId)` of each group.

But perhaps in functional notation it's clearer.

```
var res2 = persons.GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
                  .OrderBy(p => p.Min(q => q.CaseId))
                  .ToArray();
```

As it's written, the groups are ordered, not the elements "inside" the groups.

if you want even the elements inside the groups to be sorted:

```
var res3 = (from p in persons
            orderby p.CaseId
            group p by p.PersonId into q
            orderby q.Min(r => r.CaseId)
            select q).ToArray();
```

because grouping keeps the ordering of the elements (at least in LINQ to Objects. I can't guarantee it's the same in EF or LINQ-to-SQL).

Comment: But that is returning a group, I need to still have a list of Foo.

Comment: @CaffGeek Then the next time you won't write "I need to sort the list so that they grouped by PersonId"

Comment: @CaffGeek Add a `.SelectMany(p => p)` **before** any one of the `.ToArray()`.